# TeamCity Build Failed: Error: Cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, teamcity

My react app build is getting failed suddenly in Team City, I've no idea why it is happening. I can build successfully in my local.

Getting the below error in Team City

```
[Step 1/5] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     throw err;
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     ^
[15:35:58][Step 1/5] 
[15:35:58][Step 1/5] Error: Cannot find module 'e:\nodejs\12.0.0\node-v12.0.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
[15:35:58][Step 1/5] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     throw err;
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     ^
[15:35:58][Step 1/5] 
[15:35:58][Step 1/5] Error: Cannot find module 'e:\nodejs\12.0.0\node-v12.0.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
[15:35:58][Step 1/5] ExecuteStep : Failure at step 1 'Building frontend React App': LASTEXITCODE=1
[15:35:58][Step 1/5] At E:\teamcity-agent\work\d9c9e8fd3f2e0d92\Build.ps1:53 char:5
[15:35:58][Step 1/5] +     ExecuteStep 'Building frontend React App' {
[15:35:58][Step 1/5] +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,ExecuteStep
[15:35:58][Step 1/5]  
[15:35:58][Step 1/5] Process exited with code 1
```

In my package.json,

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=12.18.2"
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your TeamCity build agent requires a certain node package to be installed.